# User created groups in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, grouping

I want to let user create new group in ListView after clicking on button.

```
   private void CreateNewGroup(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create new group in MyListView
    }
```

I mean to create something like this:
[Group Items in a Windows Forms ListView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-group-items-in-a-windows-forms-listview-control)

Comment: Gimme teh codez!

Comment: @TheGeneral you're being funny today XD

Comment: @Lucifer too much coffee

Answer (score 0):

For grouping `ListView`, you could use [`CollectionViewSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource) to group the data from your item source.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" x:Name="cvs" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView Background="White" Foreground="Black"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0.5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Complete}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="Group" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
private ObservableCollection<MyClass> myClasses;
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    myClasses = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Nico", Complete = false });
    myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "LIU", Complete = true });
    myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "He", Complete = true });
    myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Wei", Complete = false });
    myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Dong", Complete = true });
    myClasses.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Ming", Complete = false });

    this.cvs.Source = myClasses;
    this.cvs.IsSourceGrouped = False;
}
```

You could group your data in group button method

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Group the data
    //Set the grouped data to CollectionViewSource

    var groups = from c in myClasses
                 group c by c.Complete;

    this.cvs.Source = groups;
    this.cvs.IsSourceGrouped = true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. I don't need automatic grouping, but groups specified by user. (creating custom groups and dragging into them items). Sorry that I didn't made it clear enough.

Comment: Please refer this code [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop).